# Get attributes from TemplateRef

Tags: angular

I try to get attribute from element, but "template.elementRef.nativeElement" is

```html
<!--->.
```

this is my code:

```js
// Parent template
<p-table  *ngIf="serias" [rows]="serias" [columns]="columns">
  <ng-template #column column="startDate" let-row="row">
    <div> {{row.startDate | date}}</div>
</ng-template>
</p-table>

// child template
@ContentChildren('column') templates : QueryList<any>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
  // Here is my problem
  this.templates['_results'].foreEach(x => this.columns["columnId"].template = x);
}
```

Comment: What attribute do you want to get? The `<template>` element only exists within Angular. It is never added to the DOM and at runtime it isn't an element.

Comment: Please give an example of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: i wont to custom mat-table, that render defult template , and if exist special template , render the special.

Answer (score 1):

Just create directive i.e. :

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'ng-template[column]',
})
```

Then you will have access to directive instances:

```
@ContentChildren(TableColumnDirective)
public columnDirectives:QueryList<TableColumnDirective>;
```